# How to load content of a text file into defined structure?

Tags: matlab

I have a `.txt` file like the following. Each column represents a 3D point `(x, y, z)` and two properties `(a, b)`.

```
1.7 5.5 -3.62   0.6 10.3    []
1.0 5.5 -3.21   0.9 12.4    []
1.2 5.9 -3.25   0.5 13.9    []
1.3 5.5 -3.19   0.9 15.9    []
1.0 5.2 -3.13   0.3 17.4    []
1.7 5.9 -3.07   0.5 19.6    []
2.5 5.5 -3.01   0.9 20.9    []
2.5 5.2 -3.95   0.4 22.9    []
```

I want the content of that text file to be loaded into a defined structure like this:

```
myStruct.X, myStruct.Y, myStruct.Z, myStruct.A, myStruct.B
```

How to do that?

Comment: have you considered to use `textscan`, the output is a cell but you can post process it to get your struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dlmread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) to read the content of your text file to some array, say `A`. This works, since you only have numerical values here. Caveat: From the documentation, starting from MATLAB R2019a:

> `dlmread` is not recommended. Use `readmatrix` instead.

Then, just use the proper [`struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html#d117e1389369) command for multiple fields and values, like so:

```matlab
A = dlmread('data.txt')
myStruct = struct('X', A(:, 1), 'Y', A(:, 2), 'Z', A(:, 3), 'A', A(:, 4), 'B', A(:, 5))
```

This results in such an output (shortened):

```
  A =
      1.70000    5.50000   -3.62000    0.60000   10.30000    0.00000
      1.00000    5.50000   -3.21000    0.90000   12.40000    0.00000
      1.20000    5.90000   -3.25000    0.50000   13.90000    0.00000
      1.30000    5.50000   -3.19000    0.90000   15.90000    0.00000
      1.00000    5.20000   -3.13000    0.30000   17.40000    0.00000
      1.70000    5.90000   -3.07000    0.50000   19.60000    0.00000
      2.50000    5.50000   -3.01000    0.90000   20.90000    0.00000
      2.50000    5.20000   -3.95000    0.40000   22.90000    0.00000

  myStruct =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      X =
         1.7000
         1.0000
         [...]

      Y =
         5.5000
         5.5000
         [...]

      Z =
         [...]

      A =
         [...]

      B =
         [...]
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** I tested the above code with Octave 5.1.0, and since it remains unclear by now, if the shown code is fully MATLAB compatible, here's another solution using [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) as also suggested in [Irreducible's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516335/how-to-load-content-of-a-text-file-into-defined-structure/58516498?noredirect=1#comment103359234_58516335):

```matlab
fid = fopen('data.txt');
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %*[^\n]')
myStruct = struct('X', C{1}, 'Y', C{2}, 'Z', C{3}, 'A', C{4}, 'B', C{5})
fclose(fid);
```

The trailing `%*[^\n]` in the format specifier is to ignore all other characters after the last `%f`.

Comment: I am getting this error: ´Error using dlmread (line 147)
Mismatch between file and format character vector.
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row number 1, field number 6) ==> []\n´

Comment: @cMinor Actually, I tested the code with Octave 5.1.0, but I would be really surprised, if MATLAB treats the input differently. Has your actual text file some special encoding, was it generated by some software? Can you please copy-paste the data given in your question to some empty text file, and test the code on that file?

Comment: I deleted the [] from my file and now has no issues

Comment: @cMinor The problem certainly occured from that, yes. Nevertheless, it would've been interesting, if `[]` is parsed as an empty numeric by Octave, but not by MATLAB. Maybe someone else can test and comment on that.